# How to add handler in dynamic datatemplate

Tags: xaml, silverlight-2.0, datatemplate

I am successfully declaring a data template in a code behind as follows:

```
    private static DataTemplate CreateTemplate(string sortMemberPath, HorizontalAlignment horzAlignment)
    {
        const string xamlFormat
            =
            "<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" >"
            + "<StackPanel > "
            + "  <TextBlock Margin=\"2,0\" VerticalAlignment=\"Center\"  HorizontalAlignment=\"_HALIGNMENT_\"  "
            +
            "              Text=\"hello there\">   "
            + "  </TextBlock> "
            + "</StackPanel>"
            + "</DataTemplate>";

        return (DataTemplate) XamlReader.Load(xamlReturned);
    }
```

But now I want to add a size changed handler by changing the line:

```
            + "<StackPanel > "
```

to

```
            + "<StackPanel  SizeChanged="SizeChangedHandler" > "
```

I have the method "SizeChangedHandler" declared in the code behind. This results in a xaml parse error when the control attempts to load at runtime. I suspect that it can't find the handler "SizeChangedHandler". How can I specify this handler so that the xaml parser is happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
  dataTemplate.VisualTree.AddHandler(StackPanel.SizeChangedEvent, new SizeChangedEventHandler(SizeChangedHandler));
```

Edit:

Ok, for Silverlight you could try with the [LoadContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.loadcontent%28VS.95%29.aspx) method of the DataTemplate that returns and UIElement to which you can atach the event. Sorry I don't have VS ready to test and see if it works atm.

Comment: It looks like in Silverlight 2 that a DataTemplate does not expose a VisualTree property.